# The number of rows gets reduced when I use merge function to merge 2 dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

If i have 1232 rows in output of one dataframe and 1255 rows in the other dataframe,then while I use merge and print output i get only 1206  records.How to solve this issue?I tried using left_on and right_on.Some of the records have null in one of the columns,and some of the null value also gets printed in the 1206 records.But I want to have all the  1255 records with null values also.

df1=first dataframe
df2=second dataframe

```
df_1_2=df1.merge(df2,left_on='month',right_on='month')
```

Comment: May be use `df1.merge(df2, how='outer', ...)`?

Comment: that works,but instead it prints 1282 records,I then use reorder_columns to print only output of df2 columns,it prints 1116 records. I want to print the number of df2 records when i use reorder_columns for df2.

Comment: Then you probably want `how='left'` of `how='right'`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use `pd.concat()` across an axis. It will basically append one df to the other. [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

Comment: When I use concat,2486 records gets printed

Comment: Right, you have to specify the axis if you want to concatenate horizontally. The exact code would be: ```df_1_2 = pd.concat( [df1, df2], axis = 1, ignore_index=True)```